# Double integral: elegant way?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to evaluate (or, if that is not feasible, bound well) some integrals of the type

$$\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U} \frac{\log x \log y}{F(x,y)} dx dy,$$
where $U = \{(x,y)\in [1,\infty)^2: F(x,y)>R\}$, $R$ is positive, and $F(x,y)$ is one of the following:

1. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} \max(x,y)$
2. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} (x+y)$
3. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} |x-y|$ or $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} \max(|x-y|,1)$.

My main concern is: how to do this without inflicting a painful mess on myself and the reader?

In case 1, (a) a direct approach is feasible but results in a mess, (b) the substitution $u = x y$ helps a great deal (I'll show how in an answer below). Can something like that (or better) be done in cases 2. and 3.?

Comment: Gromov once told me that Goncharov and Zagier were amazing in their ability to compute hard integrals.

Comment: I hope you also posted this on MathOverflow.

Comment: Haven't yet. Let me do that once I finish correcting my own answer below. :)

Comment: Just cross-posted as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412199/double-integral-int-int-log-x-log-y-fx-y-dx-dy-elegant-way . I give an idea (one that should have been obvious) in the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Let me carry out @Ninad_Munshi's suggestion in the first case, so that we can compare it with what I did yesterday.

First of all,
$$\iint_U \frac{\log x \log y}{x^\alpha y^\alpha \max(x,y)} dx dy =
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}
\mathop{\iint_U}_{x>y} \frac{dx dy}{x^{a+1} y^b} \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)},$$
where $U=\{[(x,y)\in [1,\infty)^2: (x y)^\alpha \max(x,y)>R\}$ as before. Since $x^{\alpha+1} y^\alpha>R \iff x>(R/y^{\alpha})^{1/(\alpha+1)}$ and
$(R/y^\alpha)^{1/(\alpha+1)}>y \iff R>y^{2\alpha+1}$,
$$\begin{aligned}\mathop{\iint_U}_{x>y} \frac{dx dy}{x^{a+1} y^b} &= 
\int_{1}^{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}} \frac{1}{y^b}\int_{(R/y^{\alpha})^{1/(\alpha+1)}}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{a+1}} dy+
\int_{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}}^\infty \frac{1}{y^{b}}
\int_y^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{a+1}} dy\\
&= \int_{1}^{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}} \frac{1}{y^b}\frac{1}{a (R/y^{\alpha})^{a/(\alpha+1)}} dy +
\int_{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}}^\infty \frac{1}{y^{b}} \frac{1}{a y^a} dy \\ &= \frac{1}{a R^{a/(\alpha+1)}}
\int_{1}^{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}} \frac{dy}{y^{b-\alpha a/(\alpha+1)}}  +
\frac{1}{a} \int_{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}}^\infty \frac{dy}{y^{a+b}}\\
&= \frac{1}{a R^{a/(\alpha+1)}} \cdot \frac{-\frac{1}{b-1-\alpha a/(\alpha+1)}}{y^{b-1-\alpha a/(\alpha+1)}}\bigg|_1^{R^{\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}}} + \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{(a+b-1)R^{\frac{a+b-1}{2\alpha+1}}}\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{a (a+b-1)} - \frac{\alpha+1}{a 
\left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right)}\right)
\frac{1}{R^{\frac{a+b-1}{2\alpha+1}}}
+\frac{\alpha+1}{a \left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right) R^{\frac{a}{\alpha+1}}}
\end{aligned}$$
Here the coefficient of $\frac{1}{R^{\frac{a+b-1}{2\alpha+1}}}$ simplifies to  $\frac{2\alpha+1}{(a+b-1) (\alpha a - (\alpha+1) (b-1))}$. Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{R^{\frac{a+b-1}{2\alpha+1}}} = \frac{(\log R)^2}{(2\alpha+1)^2} \frac{1}{R^{\frac{a+b-1}{2\alpha+1}}}$, it is clear that the main term will be  $\frac{1}{(2\alpha+1) (2\alpha-1)} \frac{(\log R)^2}{R^{\frac{2\alpha-1}{2\alpha+1}}}$ (multiplied by $2$, in the end; let's leave that part out for all terms). It is also clear that there will be no term proportional to $\frac{(\log R)^2}{R^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}}}$, as $\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{R^{\frac{a}{\alpha+1}}}=0$. The coefficient of $\frac{\log R}{R^{\frac{2\alpha-1}{2\alpha+1}}}$ will be
$$\begin{aligned}-  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\right) \frac{1}{(a+b-1) (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))} \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} &=
\frac{2}{(a+b-1)^2 (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} + \frac{\alpha-(\alpha+1)}{(a+b-1) (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))^2} \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} \\ &= \frac{3-2\alpha}{(2\alpha-1)^2}.
\end{aligned}$$
The coefficient of $\frac{1}{R^{\frac{2\alpha-1}{2\alpha+1}}}$ will be
$2\alpha+1$ times
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{(a+b-1) (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))} &= 
\frac{2}{(a+b-1)^3 (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))}
- \frac{2 \alpha (\alpha+1)}{(a+b-1) (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))^3}
+ \frac{\alpha-(\alpha+1)}{(a+b-1)^2 (\alpha a - (\alpha+1)(b-1))^2}
\end{aligned}$$
evaluated at $(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)$, and that is
$$\begin{aligned}(2\alpha+1) \left(\frac{2}{(2\alpha-1)^3}-\frac{2 \alpha(\alpha+1)}{2\alpha-1}- \frac{1}{(2\alpha-1)^2}\right) &=
\frac{2\alpha+1}{(2\alpha-1)^3} (-8 \alpha^4+6\alpha^2-4\alpha+3 )\\&= - (2\alpha^2+4\alpha+3) - \frac{16(\alpha^2-\alpha)}{(2\alpha-1)^3},
\end{aligned}$$
which agrees with the coefficient we had before.
The coefficient of $\frac{\log R}{R^{\frac{a}{a+1}}}$ is
$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{1}{a((a+1)(b-1)-\alpha a)}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} = \frac{a+1}{a ((a+1)(b-1)-\alpha a)^2}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha},$$ which agrees with what we had before. The coefficient of $\frac{1}{R^{\frac{a}{a+1}}}$ is
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{\alpha+1}{a \left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right)} \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)}&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}  \frac{-(\alpha+1)^2}{a \left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right)^2}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)}\\
&= \frac{(\alpha+1)^2}{a^2 \left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right)^2}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} +
\frac{2 (\alpha+1)^2\cdot (-\alpha)}{a \left((\alpha+1)(b-1)-\alpha a\right)^3}\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} \\
&= \frac{(\alpha+1)^2}{\alpha^2} + 2 (\alpha+1)^2 = 2\alpha^2 + 4 \alpha+3 + \frac{2\alpha+1}{\alpha^2},
\end{aligned}$$ which is exactly what we had before.

So all is well. But, as you can see, this is not really shorter or much easier than what we had before. (It seems to be a bit longer and a bit easier.)

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite a few things to make the computations a bit nicer. First denote $G$ as

$$F(x,y) = x^{\frac{5}{3}}y^{\frac{5}{3}}G(x,y)$$

which means $G$ now encompasses all of the change between the functions. Next denote

$$I(a,b) = \iint\limits_U \frac{\log x \log y}{x^ay^bG(x,y)}dxdy = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\iint\limits_U \frac{1}{x^ay^bG(x,y)}dxdy$$

In all cases cutting the region of integration in half at the line $x=y$ by symmetry is useful.

$\textbf{Case 1}$

$$x^{\frac{8}{3}}y^{\frac{5}{3}} > R \implies y > \left(\frac{R^3}{x^{8}}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}  $$

$$I = 2\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_{R^{\frac{3}{13}}}^\infty \int_{\max\left\{\left(\frac{R^3}{x^{8}}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}},1\right\}}^x\frac{1}{x^{a+1}y^b}dydx$$

$\textbf{Case 2}$

$$\begin{cases}u = xy \\ v = \frac{y}{x}\end{cases} \to J^{-1} = 2\frac{y}{x} \implies J = \frac{1}{2v}$$

$$x+y = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}(v+1)$$

$$\frac{u^{\frac{13}{6}}}{v^{\frac{1}{2}}}(v+1) > R \implies u > \left(\frac{vR^2}{(v+1)^2}\right)^\frac{3}{13}$$

$$I = 2\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_0^1 \int_{\max\left\{\left(\frac{vR^2}{(v+1)^2}\right)^\frac{3}{13},\frac{1}{v}\right\}}^{\infty}\frac{dudv}{2u^{a+b+\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{v}(1+v)}$$

And the same coordinate change can be used for cases 3 and 4, but now the boundary term would read

$$x-y = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}(v-1)$$

Comment: Agreed - what I gave in my answer is basically case 1 worked out until the end. I still think this is just the first, not the last, step towards a simplification.

Comment: I must have been a bit blind when I skimmed your answer earlier in the day - I missed the bit with $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}$, which is of course the key simplification. Then I realized that that was the way to go, and then I read your answer again. Oh well.

Comment: In the denominator, surely you mean $2 u^{a+b+1} v^{b+1} (1+v)$ and not $2 u^{a+b+1/2} \sqrt{v} (1+v)$? Or is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: The last equation should be $x-y = \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} (1-v)$.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Funny story, it seems we are both incorrect. The proper denominator would be $$2u^{\frac{1+b+a}{2}}v^{\frac{1+b-a}{2}}(1+v)$$ and yes you are right! The sign of $v-1$ when $v\in(0,1)$ should have tipped me off that something was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let me treat the case of $F(x,y) = x^a y^a \max(x,y)$, $a>1$. (In the above, $a=5/3$.)

We let $u = x y$. Then our double integral equals 2 I, where
$$I = \mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U}}_{x<y} \frac{\log x \log y}{x^{a} y^{a}\cdot y} dy dx =
\mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,u/x)\in U}}_{x<u/x} \frac{\log x \log \frac{u}{x}}{u^{a}\cdot u/x} \frac{du}{x} dx =
\mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,u/x)\in U}}_{x<\sqrt{u}} \frac{\log x \log \frac{u}{x}}{u^{a+1}} dx du$$
and $(x,u/x)\in U$ if and only if $u^{a+1}/x>R$. Hence, the inner integral is
$$\int_{1}^{\min(\sqrt{u},u^{a+1}/R)} \log x \log \frac{u}{x} dx =
x \left(\log \frac{x}{e} \log \frac{u e}{ x}-1\right)\big|_1^{\min(\sqrt{u},u^{a+1}/R)}$$
and so
$$\begin{aligned}I &= \int_{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}}^\infty \left(\sqrt{u} \left(\log \frac{\sqrt{u}}{e} \log \frac{u e}{\sqrt{u}} - 1\right)-(\log \frac{1}{e} \log e u - 1)\right) \frac{du}{u^{a+1}}\\
&+\int_{R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}^{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}} \left(\frac{u^{a+1}}{R} \left(\log \frac{u^{a+1}}{e R} \log \frac{u e}{u^{a+1}/R} - 1\right)-(\log \frac{1}{e} \log e u - 1)\right) \frac{du}{u^{a+1}}\\ &= \int_{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4} \log^2 u - 2\right)\; \frac{du}{u^{a+1/2}}
+\int_{R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}^{\infty} (\log u + 2)\frac{du}{u^{a+1}}\\
&+ \frac{1}{R} 
\int_{R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}^{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}} \left(-
a (a+1) \log^2 u + (2 a+1) \log e R \log u - (\log e R)^2 - 1
\right) du.
\end{aligned}$$
Let us call the integrals in the last two lines $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$, respectively. Then
$$I_1 = \left(\frac{1/4}{1/2- a} \log^2 u-
\frac{1/2}{(1/2-a)^2} \log u + \frac{1/2}{(1/2-a)^3} - \frac{2}{1/2-a}\right)\frac{1}{u^{a-1/2}} \big|_{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}}^\infty = 
\left(\frac{\log^2 R}{(2a+1)^2 (a-1/2)} + 
\frac{ \log R}{(2a+1)(a-1/2)^2}
- \frac{2 (a-1) a}{(a-1/2)^3}
\right) \frac{1}{R^{\frac{2a-1}{2a+1}}},$$
$$I_2 = \frac{-\frac{\log u}{a} -\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{2}{a} }{u^{a}} \big|_{R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}^{\infty} = 
\frac{\frac{1}{a (a+1)} \log R + \frac{2 a + 1}{a^2}}{R^{\frac{a}{a+1}}},$$
$$\begin{aligned} 
I_3 
&=\left(- a (a+1) \log^2 u + 
\left((2 a + 1) \log R + 2 a^2 + 4 a + 1\right) \log u 
-\left(\log^2  R + (2 a + 3) \log R + 2 a^2 + 4 a + 3\right)\right)u\bigg|_{R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}}^{R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}}}\\
&= \left(\frac{\log^2 R}{(2 a + 1)^2}  - \frac{\log R }{2 a + 1} 
- (2 a^2 + 4 a + 3)\right)
R^{\frac{2}{2a+1}} - 
\left(- \frac{a+2}{a+1} \log R  - (2 a^2 + 4 a + 3)\right) R^{\frac{1}{a+1}}.
\end{aligned}$$
Hence (unless I've miscalculated anything), our original integral was $2 I$, where
$$I = \frac{\frac{1}{4 a^2-1}\log^2 R -
\frac{2a-3}{(2 a -1)^2} \log R -
(2 a^2+ 4 a + 3) - \frac{2 (a-1) a}{(a-1/2)^3}
}{R^{\frac{2a-1}{2a+1}}} + \frac{\frac{a+1}{a} \log R + (2 a^2+ 4 a + 3)+\frac{2a+1}{a^2}}{R^{\frac{a}{a+1}}}.$$
There has to be a nicer way. I just spend an entire working day (ending at 4:50am) trying to get this straight, and I'm still not sure it is finally right! If that's the case for this one, let us not even think about the other ones.

(Is there an easy way to show that $I\leq \frac{\log^2 R 
}{(4 a^2-1)R^{\frac{2a-1}{2a+1}}}$ is right in a certain range?)

Answer (score 1):

Let me now work out the harder cases, starting as @Ninad_Munshi has suggested.

Let $$U(R) = \{(x,y)\in [1,\infty)\times [1,\infty): x^\alpha y^\alpha \sqrt{|x\pm y|}> R\},$$
where $\alpha>1$.  We want to estimate
$$\iint_{U(R)}\frac{\log x \log y}{x^\alpha y^\alpha \sqrt{|x\pm y|}} dx dy. $$

(I have a square root here, whereas I didn't have one in the original post. This is the question I actually need answered. To get an answer to the question originally asked, just go through what I've done below, making small changes as needed.)

First of all,
$$\iint_{U(R)}\frac{\log x \log y}{x^\alpha y^\alpha \sqrt{|x\pm y|}} dx dy = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}
\iint_{U(R)}\frac{1}{x^a y^b \sqrt{|x\pm y|}} dx dy 
\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)}
$$
Let $u = x y$, $v = y/x$. The Jacobian determinant of $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)$ equals $2 v$, and so $dx dy = du dv/2v$. Thus
$$\iint_{U(R)} \frac{dy dx}{x^a y^b \sqrt{|x\pm y|}} = 
2\mathop{\iint_{U(R)}}_{x<y} \frac{dy dx}{x^a y^b \sqrt{y\pm x}} = 
 \iint_{(u,v)\in V} \frac{du dv}{
u^{\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{1}{4}} v^{\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{3}{4}} \sqrt{v\pm 1}},
$$
since $v \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{u/v}+\sqrt{u v}}=u^{1/4} v^{3/4} \sqrt{1+v}$. Here
$$\begin{aligned}V &=\left\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times (1,\infty): u^{\alpha}\left(\sqrt{uv}\pm \sqrt{u/v}\right)>R,\; \sqrt{u/v}\geq 1, \sqrt{u v} \geq 1\right\}\\
&=\left\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times (1,\infty): u^{2 \alpha+1}(\sqrt{v}\pm1/\sqrt{v})^2>R^2,\; u\geq v\right\}.\end{aligned}$$
For given $v$,
$$\int_{u: (u,v)\in V} \frac{du}{u^{\frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{1}{4}}} = 
\int_{\max((R/(\sqrt{v}\pm 1/\sqrt{v}))^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1}},v)}^\infty \frac{du}{u^{\frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{1}{4}}} =
\frac{\max\left(R^\frac{2}{2\alpha+1}/\left(\sqrt{v}\pm 1/\sqrt{v}\right)^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1}},v
\right)^{-\left(\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}\right)}}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}
$$
Let $v_0$ be the least $v\geq 1$ such that $(v^{\alpha+1}\pm v^\alpha) \geq R$ (or $v_0=1$, if there is no such $v$). Then, in the expression above, $\max(\cdot,\cdot)$ equals $v$ if and only if $v\geq v_0$.  Now
$$\int_{v=1}^{v_0} \frac{\left(\sqrt{v}\pm 1/\sqrt{v}\right)^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1}\left(\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}\right)}}{v^{\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{3}{4}} \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv = 
\int_{v=1}^{v_0} \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{c-\frac{1}{2}}}{v^{\frac{b-a+c}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}} dv,$$
where $c = \frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\left(a+b -\frac{3}{2}\right)$, and
$$\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{v^{-\left(\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}\right)}}{v^{\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{3}{4}} \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv = 
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{b } \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv
.$$
(Incidentally, both of the expressions on the right can be written as values of hypergeometric functions, not that it's clear how that helps.)  The latter integral results in the contribution
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{b } \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv\right)
&= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} 
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right)
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{b } \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv\\
&+ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a} 
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial b}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{b } \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Since
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a} 
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right)
\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} = - \frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2},\;\;\;\;\;\;\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} 
\frac{1/2}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right)
\bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} = 
\frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3},$$
this contribution is
$$
\frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{\alpha } \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv +
 \frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\log v}{v^{\alpha} \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv
.
$$
The second contribution is $R^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1} \left(- \left(\alpha - \frac{3}{4}\right)\right)} = R^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1}
\left(\frac{3}{4}-\alpha\right)}$ times
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}
\left(
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\int_{1}^{v_0}  \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{c-\frac{1}{2}}}{v^{\frac{b-a+c}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}}  dv\right).$$
Noting that $c = \frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\left(a+b -\frac{3}{2}\right) =1 - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}$ for $a=b=\alpha$, we see that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{1}^{v_0}  \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{c-\frac{1}{2}}}{v^{\frac{b-a+c}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}}  dv= \int_{1}^{v_0} 
\left(\frac{\log (v\pm 1)}{2\alpha+1} + \frac{\log v}{2} \left(1 -
\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\right)\right) \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}} dv
,$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \int_{1}^{v_0}  \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{c-\frac{1}{2}}}{v^{\frac{b-a+c}{2}+\frac{3}{4}}}  dv= \int_{1}^{v_0} \left(\frac{\log (v\pm 1)}{2\alpha+1} + \frac{\log v}{2} \left(-1 -
\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\right)\right) \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv,$$
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b}
\int_{1}^{v_0} \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv &= 
\int_{1}^{v_0} \left(\frac{\log (v\pm 1)}{2\alpha+1} + \frac{\log v}{2} \left(-1 -
\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\right)\right) 
\left(\frac{\log (v\pm 1)}{2\alpha+1} + \frac{\log v}{2} \left(1 -
\frac{1}{2\alpha+1}\right)\right) \frac{\left(1+v\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv\\
&= 
\int_{1}^{v_0} \left(\frac{\log^2 \left(\sqrt{v}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}\right)}{(2\alpha+1)^2} - \frac{\log^2 v}{4}\right) \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv
.\end{aligned}$$
We remark that $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right) \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)} = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial b} 
\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2} -\frac{3}{4}}\right) \bigg|_{(a,b)=(\alpha,\alpha)},$ and conclude that the second contribution is $R^{\frac{2}{2\alpha+1} \left(\frac{3}{4}-\alpha\right)}$ times
$$\begin{aligned}
&
\frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3}
 \int_{1}^{v_0}   \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv\\
 - &\frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}
\int_{1}^{v_0} \frac{2 \log (\sqrt{v}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}})}{2\alpha+1} \cdot \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv \\
 + &\frac{1}{\alpha -\frac{3}{4}}
 \int_{1}^{v_0} \left(\frac{\log^2 \left(\sqrt{v}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}\right)}{(2\alpha+1)^2} - \frac{\log^2 v}{4}\right) \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv
\end{aligned}
$$

For $\alpha<2$ (as in the original example, $\alpha=5/3$), these integrals all converge even when completed (that is, extended up to $\infty$). Then we can bound our integral
$$\iint_{U(R)}\frac{\log x \log y}{x^\alpha y^\alpha \sqrt{|x\pm y|}} dx dy$$ by
$$\frac{1}{2 \left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} +{\log v}}{v^{\alpha} \sqrt{v\pm 1}} dv
+I_\pm\cdot R^{-\frac{2}{2\alpha+1} \left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)},
$$
where
$$I_\pm = \int_{1}^{\infty} 
\left(\frac{1/2}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^3}
 - \frac{ \log (\sqrt{v}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}})}{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}
+ \frac{\frac{\log^2 \left(\sqrt{v}\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}\right)}{(2\alpha+1)^2} - \frac{\log^2 v}{4}}{\alpha -\frac{3}{4}}\right) \frac{\left(v\pm 1\right)^{
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5/2}{2\alpha+1}}}{v^{\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5/4}{2\alpha+1}}}  dv
$$

In the "$-$" case, since $v_0^{\alpha+1}-v_0^\alpha=R$, it is clear that $v_0\geq R^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}$. It is also clear that
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} +{\log v}}{v^{\alpha} \sqrt{v- 1}} dv &\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-1/v_0}}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} +{\log v}}{v^{\alpha+1/2}} dv\\ &=
\frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} -
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}}{\sqrt{1-1/v_0}}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{1}{v^{\alpha+1/2}} dv\\ &=
\frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} 
+
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}+\log v_0}{\sqrt{1-1/v_0}
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) v_0^{\alpha-1/2}}.
\end{aligned}$$

Hence, we can give a total bound of
$$\frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} 
+
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}+\frac{\log R}{\alpha+1}}{2\sqrt{1-R^{-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}}
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2} R^{-\frac{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}{\alpha+1}} + I_-\cdot R^{-\frac{2\alpha-3/2}{2\alpha+1}}
$$
For $\alpha<2$, we have $\frac{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}{\alpha+1}>\frac{2\alpha-3/2}{2\alpha+1}$, and so the second term is dominant.

In the "$+$" case, $v_0^{\alpha+1}+v_0^\alpha=(v_0+1) v_0^{\alpha} R$, and so $v_0\geq R^{1/(\alpha+1)}-1$. Much as before,
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} +{\log v}}{v^{\alpha} \sqrt{v+ 1}} dv &\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/v_0}}
\int_{v=v_0}^\infty \frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} +{\log v}}{v^{\alpha+1/2}} dv\\ &=
\sqrt{1-R^{-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}}
\frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} 
+
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}+\log v_0}{
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) v_0^{\alpha-1/2}}.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the total bound now is
$$\sqrt{1-R^{-\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}}
\frac{\left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-1} 
+
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}+\frac{\log R}{\alpha+1}}{2
\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\alpha-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2} v_0^{-\alpha+\frac{1}{2}} + I_+\cdot R^{-\frac{2\alpha-3/2}{2\alpha+1}},
$$
where, again, the latter term is dominant for $\alpha<2$.